# Android library: do I need to sign it?

Tags: android, aar

As in the question. I'm about to release an Android Library for the large company. Now is the question: do I need to sign it? In particular I mean if this is needed to let an user use this library in his app so he can publish it to Google Play without any problems.

Comment: No, you don't need to sign it.